# Renaming variables dynamically by replacing a prefix with another prefix in SAS

Tags: sas, prefix

I have a lot of variables that have the same prefix, I want to replace this prefix with another one of my choosing, to be more specific, my variables are named IPN_RAORAOR1 ... IPN_RAORAOR125 IPN_VOLVOLR17 ... IPN_VOLVOLR46 and so on I want to take those IPN_RAORAO, IPN_VOLVOL etc... and replace them by IPN_RAO, IPN_VOL etc i want to work on it in a sas macro because i might encounter this problem multiple times with dozens of other datasets, now i've tried something but instead of replacing the prefix it adds one, if you could help me that would be great

```
%macro rename(inds,outds,varlist,prefixlist);

%local i vars prefix namelist renames;

%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&varlist,%str( )));
    %let vars=%scan(&varlist,&i,%str( ));
    %let prefix=%scan(&prefixlist,&i,%str( ));
    proc transpose data=&inds(obs=0 keep=&vars) out=names; run;
    proc sql noprint;

    select _name_ into : namelist separated by ' ' from names;
    quit;

    %let renames= %rename(vars=&namelist,prefix=&prefix);
    %end;

    data &outds;
    set &inds(rename=(&renames));
    run; 

%mend ; 

%rename(inds=test, outds=test2, varlist = IPN_AFFAFF: IPN_RAORAO: 
IPN_VOLVOL:, prefixlist =IPN_AFFR IPN_RAO IPN_VOL);
```

Comment: If some of the variables are character you need a VAR statement in your PROC TRANSPOSE.  With out that only the numeric variables are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of variables in your dataset from sashelp.vcolumn. This is easier than transposing an empty dataset. Also, the macro variable "renames" can be created directly in you `into:` statement using `catx()`.

In the below, I have made a new `renames&i` macro variable for each element in the list of prefixes. This makes the code a bit easier to read in my opinion. Also, I have renamed the parameters `varlist` and `prefixlist` to `oldprefixlist` and `newprefixlist`, respectively. I think these names are more appropriate.

```
%macro rename(inds,outds,oldprefixlist,newprefixlist);

   * For each pair of old and new prefixes, make a list of variables that should be renamed;
   %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&oldprefixlist,%str( )));
      proc sql noprint;
         select catx('=',name,tranwrd(name,"%scan(&oldprefixlist,&i,%str( ))","%scan(&newprefixlist,&i,%str( ))"))
            into :renames&i. separated by ' '
         from sashelp.vcolumn
         where libname='WORK' 
           and memname=upcase("&inds.")
           and index(upcase(name),upcase("%scan(&oldprefixlist,&i,%str( ))")) = 1
         ;
      quit;
   %end;

   * Make the output dataset including renamed variables;
   data &outds;
      set &inds;
      rename 
      %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&oldprefixlist,%str( )));
         &&renames&i.
      %end;;
   run; 

%mend; 


* Try it out with testdata;
data test;
input ipn_affaff1 $ ipn_raoraor1 ipn_raoraor125 $ ipn_volvolr17 $ ipn_volvolr46 $;
datalines;
a 1 b c d 
e 2 f g h
;
run;

%rename(inds           = test
       ,outds          = test2
       ,oldprefixlist  = ipn_affaff ipn_raorao ipn_volvol
       ,newprefixlist  = ipn_aff ipn_rao ipn_vol);
```

Comment: God I've looked for a proper solution for hours, this is amazing thank you very much this is simple and effective